# DJANGO int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

**Hello sir i have in DJANGO a problem tryin to get my algorithm right please help, much appreciated:**
**MYERROR:**
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'

**MYCODE:**

```
def subs(request, pk):
    sw = Swimmers.objects.filter(id=pk).values('sessions')
    sw_list = int(list(sw))
    res = sw_list +1
    print('Data:',sw)
    return JsonResponse(res, safe=False)
```

Comment: What is `int(...)` supposed to do on a list? Please share the model and explain *what* you try to do.

Comment: Thank You for the reply MY MODEL:

class Swimmers(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
 lastname = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
 idno = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, null=True)
 sessions = models.IntegerField(max_length=200, blank=False)
 totalsessions = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False )
 dateofpayment = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False)
 
 session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

 def __str__(self):
  return self.name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't convert a list to an int, my suggestion would be:

```py
sw_list = map(int, sw)
```

This will convert each of the elements of `sw` to an `int`

But you're also going to have issues because you can't increment a list either, so on the very next line you'd need something like:

```py
sw_list = map(lambda x: x + 1, sw_list)  # instead of sw_list += 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the first response, i tried the method above but stuck: local variable 'sw_list' referenced before assignment

Comment: that means you haven't used `sw_list` before, I'd have to see your code to understand, but that would need to go into a new post.

Comment: my code is the same kindly i can not yet ask new question please help below is my code

Comment: def subs(request, pk):
 sw = Swimmers.objects.filter(id=pk).values('sessions')
 sw_list = map(lambda x: x + 1, sw_list)
 return JsonResponse(res, safe=False)

Comment: ahh, see you forgot the first step of `sw_list = map(int, sw)` before `sw_list = map(lambda x: x + 1, sw_list)`

Comment: Thank YOU may you have a blessed lifetime

Comment: i am getting a new error

Comment: Object of type map is not JSON serializable

Comment: You said that this is not the best way to do be doing this. which is the best way that you recommend i wanted to be able to input a number on a form than be able to add/reduce that number by 1 whenever i click on the button reduce and be able to out put it on a table.

Comment: i added list before map

Comment: def subs(request, pk):
 sw = Swimmers.objects.filter(id=pk).values('sessions')
 sw_list = list(map(int,sw))
 sw_list = list(map(lambda x: x + 1, sw_list))
 return JsonResponse(sw_list, safe=False)

Comment: bute getting an error: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'dict'

Comment: alright, now that's something completely different, I don't know why `sw` is a `dict`

Comment: Hello Thank You Again. i managed to solve the problem of a dict by adding .first() after my queryset. Now i am faced with a new problem: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'sessions'

MYCODE
def subs(request, pk):
 sw = Swimmers.objects.filter(id=pk).values('sessions').first()
 sw_list = list(map(int, sw ))
 sw_lists = list(map(lambda x: x + 1, sw_list ))
 return JsonResponse(list(sw_lists), safe=False)